# Why does the "Run as jUnit Test" not show up for existing classes in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, junit4

I'm having problems running methods as a jUnit in Eclipse.  I know how to do so in Eclipse on my Mac and now I'm trying to get it to work on Ubuntu 12.04.

Normally, if you have a method like...

```
@Test
public void foo(){}
```

...you can right-click the `foo` method and one of the options is "Run as jUnit Test".  Since I started attempting to use jUnit test in Eclipse on my Ubuntu machine, I see this option when I define a method in a brand new class.  For example, I created a brand new class with the method `test1`:

```
package all;

import org.junit.Test;

public class BabyClass {
    @Test
    public void test1(){}
}
```

Right-clicking on `test1` gives me the "Run as jUnit Test" option and the jUnit test works as expected.

However, if I go into one of my older classes (from before I ever tried using jUnit) and try to run a method as a jUnit test by right-clicking on its name, then the run as jUnit test option isn't there, which is puzzling.  The "old" and "new" classes are all in the same package, in case that is relevant to know.

Does anyone have any ideas why the option to run as a jUnit test is not appearing for methods in my older classes?  Is there something I'm supposed to do to make the option appear?  This seems kind of like a bug in Eclipse to me.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you include the junit library in your project? Check out this link and see if it helps. http://www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html I think you have to include the junit library though before that option shows up.

Comment: I realized what my problem was.  My older classes involved generics and you cannot use jUnit for classes with generics (see below).  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do jUnit tests with classes that involve generics.

```
package all;

import org.junit.Test;

public class BabyClass<T> {
    @Test
    public void test1(){

    }
}
```

The baby class is now parameterized, but you can't do a jUnit test with it any more.